# Create separated MVC5 projects into same solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new to MVC. I created a ASP.NET MVC5 Login project (UI) using Razor engine that is authentication responsible by using OWIN (VS2013). ViewModels and Data for solution are separated and layered by DLL. I would like to create two separated MVC5 project (UI) into same solution, each one is like a subsystem (eg: Accounting project, Inventory project, etc). Always user has to pass authentication project (Login) first and then according its necessity navigate to Accounting or Inventory subsystem.

My goal is that I could add or remove subsystems when deploying according company negotiation that let it use one or any subsystem.

How can I achieve that?
Every subsystem must be created using a separated ASP.NET MVC5 project template or can be created by a separated DLL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use areas.  See http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/article.php/c20227/Using-Areas-in-ASPNET-MVC-Application.htm

What are Areas?

Areas are functionally independent modules of your ASP.NET MVC application that mimic the folder structure and conventions of MVC. Consider the following scenario :

Comment: Thanks, however, ¿How could I do to dynamically remove or supress a functionally area when is requiered? I want to avoid recompiling.